# np.array returns different dimensions of the array for the same data

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to convert the list of ndarray to ndarray of ndarray. In the first case I'm splitting the original array into 5 pieces using the np.array_split function, as a result i have list of ndarray, then I transform this list using the np.array() function and get ndaray with shape (5,). In the second case i do the same but with other data and  as a result I get ndarray with shape (5,200,3072). The only difference between the data is their shape. In first case it is (121, 3072), in second case (1000,3072).

Here shape will be (5,)

```
train_folds_X = []
train_folds_X = np.array_split(binary_train_X,5,axis = 0)
np.array(train_folds_X).shape
```

but here shape will be (5,200,3072)

```
train_folds_X = []
train_folds_X = np.array_split(train_X,5,axis = 0)
np.array(train_folds_X).shape
```

binary_train_X shape is (121,3072), train_X shape(1000,3072) in other it is same data,this is number from Street View House Numbers (http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/) but in binary_train_X only 0 and 9. train_folds_X before using the np.array in the first and second cases have the same len = 5. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: take a look at my answer; however, imo your question is a bit misleading when you say "for the same data", because your examples present applying np.array to two different data :) Unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in the first case the result of the split is a list of **uneven** arrays; look at this:

```
y = np.empty([121,3072])
[np.array_split(y,5,axis = 0)[i].shape for i in range(5)]
```

which returns the first array a bit bigger than the others:

```
[(25, 3072), (24, 3072), (24, 3072), (24, 3072), (24, 3072)]
```

and thus the resulting shape of:

```
np.array(np.array_split(y,5,axis = 0)).shape
```

is `(5,)`. Plus you should get a deprecation warning:

```
Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
```

On the other hand the second case behaves as expected:

```
z = np.empty([1000,3072])
[np.array_split(z,5,axis = 0)[i].shape for i in range(5)]
```

returns:

```
[(200, 3072), (200, 3072), (200, 3072), (200, 3072), (200, 3072)]
```

and thus the resulting array can be constructed as you expect:

```
np.array(np.array_split(z,5,axis = 0)).shape
```

returns `(5, 200, 3072)`